# Changing a character globably

Tags: python

So im trying out a some stuff in python, like math, quizzes, simple calculator and other stuff, ive been donig this for about a 3 weeks and have completed them mostly without help but a simple thing i wanted to try i found out to be much harder than i thought, and it is simply how to change a charactor universily, like when it prints a t it will always be a i, i would like to know if this is possible and how to do it, looking forward to a response.
i also searched alot on the internett but there dosent seem to be an answer anywhere, maybe this thread will help others too.

I tried name.replace("bla bla", "blah blah"
it does work but dosent chane every bla bla to blah blah

note: this is just for testing, and was just wondering if it was possible
and im sorry for beinga little unclear, the thing i was wondering was if it was able to change a charactor to always be another like every time i for example print("Hello") that no matter what it will always come out in the form of Helli because the o is replaced

Comment: Your example will change every occurrence of "bla bla" inside the string in `name`.  There is, of course, no global method to filter every output.  That would be silly.  Perhaps you should show a larger example of what you want.

Comment: Please provide code samples and what you are expecting the behavior to be. str.replace should replace all instances eg
>>> x = "bla bla foo blah blah"
>>> x.replace("bla", "blah")
'blah blah foo blahh blahh'

Comment: Why would you want to globally change all output like that? Do you really want all subsequent `print` output, regardless of what it's printing or why, to be silently intercepted and changed?

Comment: i sorry i was a little unclear but i meant if it was possible to always change a i to o i edited some more information in the main text, but it was just a question and i have to real reason, it was simply me wanting to learn python and wondering if it was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly - the `str.replace()` method is indeed the right tool for the job, but it seems like you might not be using it correctly or there's a misunderstanding in its behavior.

The `str.replace(old, new[, count])` method returns a copy of the string with all occurrences of the substring `old` replaced by `new`. If the optional argument `count` is given, only the first `count` occurrences are replaced.

Here's how you would typically use it to replace all occurrences of the character 't' with 'i':

```py
text = "this is a test"
new_text = text.replace('t', 'i')
print(new_text)  # "ihis is a iesi"
```

This will replace every 't' in the string with an 'i'.

However, if you want this to happen universally -- meaning, anytime you print something, a 't' would automatically be replaced with an 'i' without you having to call `replace` every time -- you would need to write a custom print function that does this replacement for you before printing:

```py
def custom_print(text):
    text = text.replace('t', 'i')
    print(text)

# Now when you use custom_print, it will replace 't' with 'i'
custom_print("this is a test")  # "ihis is a iesi"
```

If `replace` isn't working as expected, make sure that you are using the return value of `replace`, since strings in Python are immutable and `replace` does not change the original string but returns a new one.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you this answered my question and sorry if i was a bit unclear i just started and dont know that much, im doing this on my own so my only way of getting help is either here or searching. learn new thing every day.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help 

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by Danyil, you may also want to check out maketrans() and translate() methods of string variables.

Here is an example:

```
transitionTable = str.maketrans('t','i','!')
testString = "It is not a tumor!"
newString = testString.translate(transitionTable)
print(f"{testString} \n"
      f"{newString}")

#Output:
#It is not a tumor! 
#Ii is noi a iumor
```

You may read more on them [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-maketrans-translate-functions/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this also helped and i will try this too, for me its nice to just learn a bunch of methodes and codes and then use them myself to learn more, so this helped

Comment: I'm happy to help)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the standard stdout with one that does the replacement. There's perhaps a cleaner way, but this does print `prini`:

```py
import sys
stdout = sys.stdout
class Sidoui:
    def write(data):
        stdout.write(data.replace('t', 'i'))
    def flush():
        stdout.flush()
sys.stdout = Sidoui

print('print')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3d2XmFuQXlSgUVxZzFZek5JeWKNiCOHoQDldyTmJxsUJwJpCTacWlAAQpqWkK5UWZJakaKYkliZoQQRCA6NBDyOkVpRbkJCanaqiXqOsoqGeqa2rCTUjLKS3O0MDUDRXnQjgB6B6I9VxcBUWZeSUa6mBKXRPiA6hHYB4CAA)

Comment: Nice, this worked